# SQL Query to find records having certain records in a has_many through relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have following models:

```
# contributor.rb

class Contributor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :skill_groupings
  has_many :skills, through: :skill_groupings
end

# skill_grouping.rb

class SkillGrouping < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :skill
  belongs_to :contributor
end

# skill.rb

class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :skill_groupings
  has_many :contributors, through: :skill_groupings
end
```

I want to search (SQL query) for the contributors whose skill_ids contain **all** the values included in an array.

Suppose data are the following:

```
contributor_1.skill_ids: [2, 3, 6, 7]
contributor_2.skill_ids: [4, 7]
contributor_3.skill_ids: [9]
contributor_4.skill_ids: []

wanted_ids = [3, 7]
```

`Contributor.joins(:skill_groupings).where(skill_groupings: { skill_id: wanted_ids }).distinct` returns the contributors which have 3 *or* 7 in their skill ids, hence `[contributor_1, contributor_2]`. This is not what I want.

The result of the query should be `[contributor_1]`, because only `contributor_1` has **all** the skill ids in `wanted_ids`.

Unfortunately, `skill_ids` seems to be only an attribute introduced by Rails and not available in SQL.

How can I achieve this only by means of SQL queries?

Comment: Does `Contributor.where(id: Contributor.select(:id).joins(:skills).where(skills: { id: wanted_ids }).group(:id).having("COUNT(skills.id) = #{wanted_ids.uniq.size}"))` work for you

Comment: @engineersmnky yes thanks, but isn't that a bit too long and cumbersome? Does a simpler query exist?

Comment: IMO this is the simplest way to achieve what you are trying to do and this is how I would have gone about it in pure SQL (Which would be a lot longer). Since this is postgres the following should work and shortens it a bit `Contributor.joins(:skills).where(skills: { id: wanted_ids }).group(:id).having("COUNT(skills.id) = #{wanted_ids.uniq.size}"))`. This works because postgres allows you to group by the identity column while still returning all the columns (does not work in most other SQL databases)

Comment: @engineersmnky if you write your comment as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that a contributor cannot have the same skill more than once, the simplest way I can see going about this is to find all the contributors with these skills that have the same number of skills as the skills passed in e.g.

```
Contributor.joins(:skills)
  .where(skills: { id: wanted_ids })
  .group(:id)
  .having("COUNT(skills.id) = #{wanted_ids.uniq.size}"))
```

This will result in the following SQL given `wanted_ids = [3, 7]`

```
SELECT 
  contributors.*
FROM 
  contributors 
  INNER JOIN skill_groupings ON skill_groupings.contributor_id = contributors.id
  INNER JOIN skills ON skills.id = skill_groupings.skill_id
WHERE
  skills.id IN (3,7)
GROUP BY 
  contributors.id 
HAVING 
  COUNT(skills.id) = 2
```

This will only work for PostgreSQL because this SQL server allows for grouping by a primary key while still selecting the whole row of columns. For other databases you will need a sub subquery such as:

```
Contributor.where(id: 
  Contributor.joins(:skills)
    .select(:id)
    .where(skills: { id: wanted_ids })
    .group(:id)
    .having("COUNT(skills.id) = #{wanted_ids.uniq.size}")
)
```